# AngularJS Lexer Error while trying to insert $scope variable in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to make an array of objects inside an AngularJS controller, so that I can iterate over the objects in the view. The view consists of a section that allows a user to enter a map with a name and north, south, east and west coordinates.

In my controller, I currently have this:

```
$scope.maps= [];

$scope.maps.push({
    name: $scope.mapName,
    nord: $scope.mapNorth,
    sued: $scope.mapSouth,
    ost: $scope.mapEast,
    west: $scope.mapWest
});
```

What I am trying to do is to make an array of objects (maps), which I can then iterate over with ng-repeat, because I want the user to be able to specify multiple maps.

But when I load the page, I get:

```
Lexer Error: Unexpected next at column{1} in expression [{2}].
```

I looked at the link that Angular gave me and it spells "nextharacter" at one point. I changed it to "nextcharacter" and got this:

```
Lexer Error: Unexpected nextcharacter  at columns 7-7 [ß] in expression [mapScale].
```

I am still not any smarter by this. In my HTML, I have specified the view like this:

and, further down:

```
          <input id="v_i6" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="number" ng-model="mapScale"
```

- Why is it giving me errors about mapScale, even though I did not even use that variable in JS?
- Is this the correct way to add $scope variables to a JS array of objects, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Should be fine - look in your HTML - did you miss a quote or something? Paste your HTML into a raw text editor and verify there are no symbols in it

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I forgot that JavaScript does not like umlauts or characters like "ß" in variable names. I translated the variable names for this example the original was "karteMaßstab" instead of "mapScale" and Angular got stuck on the "ß".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not use an "ß" character. I am sorry that I asked, but I forgot that you can't use "ß", umlauts or other foreign characters in AngularJS.